# Accidental echo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

When I was setting up my Ubuntu environment, I think I mistyped and did something like this:

```
echo 'srouce /opt/whatever'
```

And now when I open terminal, the first line is always:

```
srouce: command not found
```

How can I get fix this issue?

Comment: It shouldn't happen. Have you redirected echo to `~/.bashrc` or something like that?

Comment: Hi, perhaps use "source", was it misspelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the misspelling in your shell startup files:

```
sed -i 's/srouce/source/' .bashrc .profile
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. I'm not sure what it does, but I'll look it up once I get the time.